# PyCharm - Characters with underscore

Tags: pycharm

I've observed that some words have specific characters underlined, like this :
[image: pycharm_underscored_characters]

What is their usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are keyboard shortcuts - clicking on it will activate the menu items.
You start with Alt+character and then continue by clicking the character of the item. In your example, you click Alt+E and then click o and the item will be actiavted

Comment: And 'Alt+ ' works for other programs as well! (i.e. Google Chrome). Thank you.